# How to enable translation for custom post types and custom taxonomies using Polylang on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, multilingual, polylang

I am using Neptune Theme for Food Recipe Bloggers & Chefs on Wordpress. I am trying to translate the custom post type : osetin_recipe

In the plugin settings, I checked the boxe to enable the translation for the post type :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tIQM.png)

Whan I save the changes, I notice that :
All my recipe pages no longer show up on the admin panel and also on my website
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWCdf.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m3eq.jpg)

I did read the documentation https://polylang.pro/doc/filter-reference/#pll_get_post_types and tried to use the pll_get_post_types code.

I replaced the 'my_cpt' with 'osetin_recipe', but when I do it the check box from the first screen shot simply disappear. What should I do?